# How to store the result of a python function in robot framework and display it in Reports?

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, appium-android, python-appium

I am testing an app that uses Bluetooth,
I have a python function that connects it to a server and displays some strings.
I want to store that strings in variable and compare it with it other strings.

I have stored the results in the result variable but can use it compare the strings

```
*** Settings ***
Library         AppiumLibrary     run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot
Library         String
Library         bt.py
*** Variable ***
${appium_1}=     http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
${platform_name}=    android
${platformVersion}=         9
${deviceName}=          b6722e70
${app}=      /home/user/Downloads/pre-prod.apk
${result}
*** Test Cases ***
App_Test_1
[Documentation]    Test Case to Login
Open Application        ${appium_1}     
platformName=${platform_name}       deviceName=${deviceName}        
app=${app}     
Capture Page Screenshot
Click Element   id=com.vendekin:id/intro_btn_skip
Sleep   4
Wait Until Element Is Visible   id=com.vendekin:id/phone
input text      id=com.vendekin:id/phone    
Click Element   id=com.vendekin:id/login
Sleep   5
Wait Until Element Is Visible   id=com.vendekin:id/otp  
Click Element   id=com.vendekin:id/otp
sleep  15
Wait Until Element Is Visible   id=com.vendekin:id/login
Click Element   id=com.vendekin:id/login
Sleep   6
Input Text  id=com.vendekin:id/promocode    010331
sleep   2
click element   id=com.vendekin:id/add
${result}=           connect     29476601-52BE-11CB-8642-D50A896F8D2A
log  ${result}
capture page screenshot
quit application
```

I expected that the output of the function would be stored in the result as a string to compare but it shows "None"

Comment: Your function `connect` should use `return` statement if you want to pass back something to robotframework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a variable to get the return value of a function, that function must return it in the first place. Getting a `None` means your function doesn't (or returns a literal `None` :).

So `connect` must be something like this:

```
def connect(data):
    output = does_its_magic(data)
    return output
```

Comment: Here, I want to store the output in a variable of the robot framework. In this case, I want to store the values returned by the output variable in ${Result}